# How to get data from database according to string length without using any string function

Tags: database, jdbc, multiple-databases, string-length

I have to get the records from a table field where Length of record/data/string is greater then 8 characters. I cannot use any string function as the query has to be used on (MySQL, MSSQL, Oracle).

I don't want to do the below EXAMPLE:

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
String st = select 'name' from table;

rs = executeSQL(st);
if ( rs != null )
{
    rs.next();
    names.add(rs.getString(1));
}

for(String name : names)
{
    if(name.length() > 8)
    result.add(name);
}
```

Any idea other then the one coded above? A query that can get the required result instead of processing on the retrieved data and then getting the required result.

Thank you for any help / clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JDBC Drivers may implement a JDBC escapes for the functions listed in appendix D (Scalar Functions) of the JDBC specification. A driver should convert the scalar functions it supports to the appropriate function on the database side. A list of the supported functions can be queried using 'DatabaseMetaData.getStringFunctions()'

To use this in a query you would then either use `CHAR_LENGTH(string)` or `LENGTH(string)` like :

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE {fn CHAR_LENGTH(field)} > 8
```

You can replace `CHAR_LENGTH` with `LENGTH`. The driver (if it supports this function) will then convert it to the appropriate function in the underlying database.

From section *13.4.1 Scalar Functions* of the JDBC 4.1 specification:

> Appendix D “Scalar Functions" provides a list of the scalar functions
>   a driver is expected to support. A driver is required to implement
>   these functions only if the data source supports them, however.
>
> The escape syntax for scalar functions must only be used to invoke the
>   scalar functions defined in Appendix D “Scalar Functions". The escape
>   syntax is not intended to be used to invoke user-defined or vendor
>   specific scalar functions.

Comment: @SardarFaisal I think JDBC escapes aren't used a lot, so it isn't widely known.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be better off leveraging the power of the database and implementing a [factory](http://www.oodesign.com/factory-pattern.html) for your SQL statements (or perhaps for objects encapsulating your SQL functionality).

That way you can configure your factory with the name/type of the database, and it'll give you the appropriate SQL statements for that database. It gives you a clean means of parameterising this info, whilst allowing you to leverage the functionality of your databases and not having to replicate the database functionality in a suboptimal fashion in your code.

e.g.

```
   DabaseStatementFactory fac = DatabaseStatementFactory.for(NAME_OF_DATABASE);
   String statement = fac.getLongNames();
   // then use this statement. It'll be configured for each db type
```

It's probably wise to encapsulate further and use something like:

```
   DabaseStatementFactory fac = DatabaseStatementFactory.for(NAME_OF_DATABASE);
   List<String> names = fac.getLongNames();
```

such that you're not making assumptions re. common schema and means of queries etc.

Comment: Yes Brian you are right but here I get no clue of what database is queried. I just have to provide the query to another component which retrieves and returns the data. If I understood what you said then it seems not possible in my scenario. Thank you

Comment: Another solution that I found is:

Select name from table where name like '________';

Answer (score 1):

Another solution that I found is:

```
Select name from table where name like '________';
```

SQL counts the underscore (_) characters and return a name of length equal to number of underscore characters.